# Get specific true coordinates of the Bitmap inside an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-drawable

I have an `custom  ImageView` which i `setBitmap()` to , the `Bitmaps` are all with `dimensions of 800x600` .

i set up on touch event which i draw rectangles on top of the view , and later on i want to take these rectangle coordinates and send them back to the server for update.

the problem is that the **event.getX** and **event.getY** return the relative /maybe scaled coordinates **(somewhere with dimension of 2000*1700)**

and i wish to get the real bitmap coordinates.

**the xml defining the view** :

```
<com.example.tombushmits.drawtesting.DrawbleImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
```

and on my **onTouch**  in my `custom ImageView` :

```
switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(rec_list.size()<5) {
                    drawRectangle = true;
                    xTop = event.getX();
                   yTop = event.getY();
                   xBottom = event.getX();
                   yBottom = event.getY();
//                    float x = event.getRawX();
//                    float y = event.getRawY();
//                    truex= (x-location[0])*width_ratio;
//                    truey = (y-location[1])*height_ratio;
//
                   invalidate();


               }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(rec_list.size() <5) {
                    xBottom = event.getX();
                    yBottom = event.getY();
                    invalidate();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//ignore
//                truex_end = (event.getX()-location[0])*width_ratio;
//                truey_end = (event.getY()- location[1])*height_ratio;
                if(rec_list.size() < 5) {
                    drawRectangle = false;

                    rec_list.add(new Rect((int) xTop, (int) yTop, (int) xBottom, (int) yBottom));
                    true_rec_list.add(new Rect((int)truex,(int)truey,(int)truex_end,(int)truey_end));
                    invalidate();

                }
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(clear)
        {
            canvas.drawRect(0,0,0,0,paint);
            rec_list.clear();
            clear =false;
            return;

        }
        for(Rect rect:rec_list)
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
        if(drawRectangle)
            canvas.drawRect(xTop, yTop, xBottom, yBottom, paint);

    }

    public ArrayList<Rect> returnRecs(){
//        return this.rec_list;
        return this.true_rec_list;
    }
```

much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the coordinates of the ImageView via the View.getLocationOnScreen() method in your onTouch. This will give you the top left coordinates. Since you know the size of your bitmaps you can then calculate any other coordinates you might need.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    v.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    // location array now has x and y coordinates
}
```